# Should we have a list of 'general references' in meta to help with very simple questions?

Tags: discussion

https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says that 'general reference' questions are off topic. This is so that people don't come along with ultra-simple questions that would be easily answered by a pre-existing reference.

Should we make a short list (perhaps here in meta) of places people could look before posting here?

I'm thinking this could include

- dictionaries
- pronunciation guides
- easily-searchable grammar references

We haven't actually had many people coming and asking really simple questions, but in the interest of being able to respond in a friendly and helpful way if we do, what do people think of starting a simple list? (it wouldn't be intended to be comprehensive - in fact, it should be short, as if something's hard to find in a general reference then it probably *can* be asked here).

Comment: I can't look it up right now but I think there have been a few very simple questions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why not?

This sort of thing has been done on other per-site metas.  A community wiki list of resources.  The best one that I know of is on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site - at [this post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/4376).

On one hand this provides a (fairly) regularly updated list of places to go for those newcomers that read the meta site before posting.
On the other, a link to it is often posted to questions that may otherwise get closed.

If it works well on other sites, it should work well here.